# How to calculate the average number of guesses made to guess a number between 0 and 31?

Tags: probability, random

I know this question is very basic, but my question is more about Mathematical thinking. How to think mathematically:

> Suppose person $A$ chooses a number from numbers between $0$ and $31$, and person $B$ has to guess which number he chose. Suppose $B$ will guess by *Linear Search*, i.e. they will check $1$, if incorrect then they will guess $2$ if incorrect, they will guess $3$ and so on $\dots$

If $A$ had chosen 1, then $B$ would make $1$ guess; if $A$ had chosen $30$, then $B$ would make $30$ guesses. So the question is: **How many guesses does $B$ make *on average*?**

I have been told that the answer is $15$.

My question is how? How would I know that B will make $15$ guesses on average?

Comment: You know that the number is evenly distributed so if you add $0$ to $31$ you get $496$ and then divide that by $32$ to get $15.5$. Since you cannot make half a guess you get your answer.

Comment: "...between 0 and 31..." but then $B$ starts at $1$ and stops at $30$. There is some typo here.

Comment: Moreover you should the way that $A$ chooses his number. From the result is implied that he chooses his number uniformly at random but this is not stated somewhere in the text.

Comment: @JohnDouma Assuming the desired "average" is the mean value, we can and do accept a fractional average even though all possible outcomes are whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a symmetry argument for you.  Call an ordering of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,31\}$ a *strategy*.  Two sample strategies are $0,1,2,\ldots, 31$ and $0,31,1,30,\ldots,15,16$.  Each strategy leads to a payoff, depending on what number A picked.

Now, for each strategy, there is an "opposite" strategy, which consists of the same numbers in opposite order.  The opposite strategy to $0,1,2,\ldots, 31$ is $31,\ldots, 2,1,0$.  Now, suppose we play the game twice.  A must pick the same number both times.  B can pick whatever strategy he or she wants for the first game, but must pick the opposite strategy for the second game.  It is easy to see that regardless of what number A picks, and regardless of the strategy B uses, for the two games combined the total number of guesses will be exactly 33.  Hence, on average, it takes 16.5 guesses (33/2).

Since every strategy has exactly one opposite, we can see that on average it takes 16.5 guesses (not 15).  This assumes that 0 and 31 are valid numbers.  If not, then 15.5 is  correct.

Comment: Don't two games actually required $33$ guesses? The game does not end until $B$ has guessed the number, so $B$ must make that guess twice (once in each game), and all other guesses once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean $A$ is selecting from the numbers $1, 2, \dots, 29, 30$.

We're going to have to assume $A$ chooses uniformly at random (that is, with probability $\frac{1}{30}$ for each number).

Then write $X_a$ for the number of guesses $B$ makes, given that $A$ picked number $a$.
We have $X_a = a$, because if $A$ picked $1$ then $B$ guesses once and is correct on that guess, so $X_1 = 1$, and so on.

Then the mean of the $X_a$ is what we're looking for, and that is $$\mathbb{E}(X_A) = \sum_{a=1}^{30} \mathbb{P}(A = a) \mathbb{E}(X_A \mid A = a) = \sum_{a=1}^{30} \frac{1}{30} \times a = \frac{1}{30} \sum_{a=1}^{30} a = \frac{1}{30} \times \frac{30 \times 31}{2}$$

That is $$\frac{31}{2} = 15.5$$